# Wrapper methods duplication

Tags: c++, wrapper

Let's say I have the following interface

```
struct I
{
    void f() = 0;
}
```

And I have a wrapper class that implements it

```
struct C
{
    void f() {}
};

struct M : I
{
    void f() override
    {
        c.f();
    }
    C c;
}
```

Furthermore, wrapper class is then extended with another wrapper in it, so it looks like this

```
struct I
{
    void f() = 0;
};

struct C
{
    void f() {}
};

struct M2
{
    void f()
    {
         c.f();
    }

    C c;   
};

struct M : I
{
    void f() override
    {
        for(const auto& it : m2map)
        {
            it.second.f();
        }  
    }

    std::map<int, M2> m2map;
}
```

If I want to add another method or change its signature, I need to do it in all classes. I don't like that all these `f()` aren't connected with each other, they are just named the same for convenience. Is there some way to "link" them, maybe add another interface?

Comment: I think you forgot `virtual` in there.

Comment: If you want to link them, why not make `C` and `M2` derive from `I` as well?

Comment: But if you talking about a way to force containment to follow a specific protocol internally, that's right out

Comment: I was referring to `I` missing `virtual`. But if you derive `C` from `I` you don't need the `M2` wrapper class at all but you have to store pointer to `I` (use unique_ptr). You can also use an array, vector or (unordered)set instead of the map.

Comment: Another way is to use type erasure to wrap the `C` and `C::f` in a struct that erases their type. You can then put that into a container. In both cases you have to create a type that is the same for all the pairs of object + member function or you can't put them into a container.